# Resolving 403 Forbidden error in a fresh Laravel 11 installation

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-11

I'm utilizing Nginx on CentOS with the Aapanel control panel. I have installed the latest Laravel 11 on my server, but when I attempt to access it, I encounter a 403 forbidden error.

I've attempted various modifications in the .htaccess files, but none have been successful. I've searched extensively online but have yet to find any useful resources.

My URL rewrite configurations are as follows:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html index.php;
}
```